Pub/Sub push subscription push endpoint in FastAPI
I am using FastAPI and now need an endpoint that can be used to push Pub/Sub messages to. I am trying to use the following piece of code:
@app.post("/")
async def pubsub_endpoint(
    payload: dict,
    db_session: Session = Depends(get_db),
):
    if environ.get("PYTHON_ENV", "") == "production":
        payload = payload["message"]
    return ProductController(db_session, payload).execute()

But I get the error:

405 Method Not Allowed

Please suggest on how I can update this endpoint to get it to work with Pub/Sub push subscription.

405 indicates that you're not making a POST request to the endpoint, but that's the only thing you've registered for /. What does your request actually look like?
